# does soapui 4.5.2 support wsdl 2.0 web service

Tags: soapui, wsdl-2.0

does soapui latest (4.5.2) support wsdl 2.0:

there is no answer for this question:

http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14048

http://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/feature-requests/250/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it doesn't support WSDL 2.0 even in the latest version (5.0).